# Polymer: Animating iron-selector with neon-animation

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

To illustrate the problem I'm experiencing, I put together a little `accordion-menu` element based on [version 1.0.7 of Polymer's `<seed-element>` boilerplate](https://github.com/PolymerElements/seed-element/tree/v1.0.7). To create your own copy of this element, follow these six steps:

1. Download the `<seed-element>` boilerplate linked to above
2. Open bower.json, replace all instances of "seed-element" with "accordion-menu", and replace the dependencies with this:

   ```
   "neon-animation": "PolymerElements/neon-animation#1.2.3",
   "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#1.4.0"
   ```
3. Rename "seed-element.html" to "accordion-menu.html" and replace its contents with this:

   ```
   <!--
   @license
   Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
   This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
   The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
   The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
   Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
   subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
   -->

   <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../neon-animation/animations/slide-down-animation.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../neon-animation/animations/slide-up-animation.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../neon-animation/neon-animation-runner-behavior.html">

   <!--
   @demo demo/index.html
   -->

   <dom-module id="accordion-menu">
     <template>
       <style>
         :host {
           display: block;
           box-sizing: border-box;
         }

         /deep/ .accordion-title {
           display: block;
           padding: 8px;
           color: #fff;
         }

         /deep/ .accordion-title:before {
           margin-right: 5px;
         }

         /deep/ div:not(.iron-selected) .accordion-title {
           background-color: #444;
           cursor: pointer;
         }

         /deep/ div:not(.iron-selected) .accordion-title:hover {
           background-color: #777;
         }

         /deep/ div:not(.iron-selected) .accordion-title:before {
           content: "\25BA";
         }

         /deep/ .iron-selected .accordion-title {
           background-color: #070;
         }

         /deep/ .iron-selected .accordion-title:before {
           content: "\25BC";
         }

         /deep/ .accordion-content {
           display: none;
         }

         /deep/ .iron-selected .accordion-content {
           display: block;
         }
       </style>

       <iron-selector selected="0"><content></content></iron-selector>
     </template>

     <script>
       Polymer({
         is: 'accordion-menu',

         properties: {
           animationConfig: {
             value: function() {
               return {
                 'entry': {
                   name: 'slide-down-animation',
                   node: this.root.querySelector('iron-selector').root.querySelector('.iron-selected'),
                 },
               }
             }
           },
         },

         'listeners': {
           'iron-deselect': 'onDeselect',
           'iron-select': 'onSelect',
         },

         'behaviors': [
           Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior,
         ],

         onDeselect: function(e) {
           var deselectedItem = e.detail.item;
           // this.playAnimation('exit');
         },

         onSelect: function(e) {
           var selectedItem = e.detail.item;
           this.playAnimation('entry');
         }
       });
     </script>
   </dom-module>
   ```
4. Replace the contents of "demo/index.html" with this:

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <!--
   @license
   Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
   This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
   The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
   The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
   Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
   subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
   -->
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
       <title>accordion-menu Demo</title>
       <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="import" href="../../paper-styles/demo-pages.html">
       <link rel="import" href="../accordion-menu.html">
     </head>
     <body unresolved>

       <p>An example of <code>&lt;accordion-menu&gt;</code>:</p>

       <accordion-menu>
         <div>
           <span class="accordion-title">Section 1</span>
           <div class="accordion-content">
             <p>Section 1's content</p>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div>
           <span class="accordion-title">Section 2</span>
           <div class="accordion-content">
             <p>Section 2's content</p>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div>
           <span class="accordion-title">Section 3</span>
           <div class="accordion-content">
             <p>Section 3's content</p>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div>
           <span class="accordion-title">Section 4</span>
           <div class="accordion-content">
             <p>Section 4's content</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </accordion-menu>

     </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Run `bower install`
6. Use `polyserve` to see the demo

When you click on any of the section titles, the section shows like it should, but it does not animate. The console has this error message:

`Couldnt play ( entry [Object] ). TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

I know the problem is what I have at line 82 of "accordion-menu.html":

`node: this.root.querySelector('iron-selector').root.querySelector('.iron-selected'),`

What should I put instead of what I have above?

Comment: why do you import *demo-pages.html* ?

Comment: @Supersharp To make the demo page prettier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the node changes depending on the selected item, I would do the following.

Remove the

```
node: this.root.querySelector('iron-selector').root.querySelector('.iron-selected')
```

from

```
           return {
              'entry': {
                name: 'slide-down-animation',
                node: this.root.querySelector('iron-selector').root.querySelector('.iron-selected'),
              },
            }
```

and change the

```
onSelect: function(e) {
        var selectedItem = e.detail.item;
        this.playAnimation('entry');
      }
```

to

```
 onSelect: function(e) {
        var selectedItem = e.detail.item;
        this.animationConfig.entry.node = selectedItem.querySelector(".accordion-content");
        this.playAnimation('entry');
      }
```